# Converting Repeated Measures Code in SAS to Equivalent in R

Tags: r, anova

I am attempting to convert existing SAS code I have for a research project into R.  I am, unfortunately, finding myself totally clueless on how to approach this for repeated measures ANOVA despite a few hours of looking at other people's questions across both StackExchange and the web at large.  I suspect this may at least, if not in total, be due to my not knowing the right questions to ask and limited statistics background.

First, I will present some sample data (tab-delimited, which I'm not sure will be preserved on SE), then explain what I'm attempting to do, and then the code I have written as of this moment.

**Sample data:**

```
Full data frame at: http://grandprairiefriends.org/document/data.df

Obs SbjctID Sex Treatment   Measured    BirthDate   DateStarted DateAssayed SubjectAge_Start_days   SubjectAgeAssay.d.  PreMass_mg  PostMass_mg DiffMass_mg PerCentMassDiff Length_mm   Width_mm    PO1_abs_min PO1_r2  PO2_abs_min PO2_r2  ProteinConc_ul  Protein1_net_abs    Protein1_mg_ml  Protein1_adjusted_mg_ml Protein2_net_abs    Protein2_mg_ml  Protein2_adjusted_mg_ml zPO_avg_abs_min z_Protein_avg_adjusted_mg_ml    POPer_ug_Protein    POPer_ug_Protein_x1000  ImgDarkness1    ImgDarkness2    ImgDarkness3    ImgDarkness4    DarknessAvg AGV_1_1 AGV_1_2 AGV_2_1 AGV_2_2 AGV_12_1    AGV_12_2    z_AGV   predicted_premass   resid_premass   predicted_premass_calculated    resid_premass_calculated    predicted_postmass_calculated   resid_postmass_calculated   predicted_postmass  resid_postmass  ln_premass_mg   ln_postmass_mg  ln_length   ln_melanization ln_po   sqrt_p
1   aF001   Female  a   PO_P    08/05/09    09/06/09    09/13/09    32  39  282.7   309.4   26.66   9.43    10.1    5.3 0.0175  0.996   0.0201  0.996   40  0.227   0.960   0.960   0.234   1.030   1.030   0.0188  0.995   0.00031 0.31491 33.7045 35.9165 28.8383 30.3763 32.2089 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5.660963    -0.016576413    4.077123    1.567263    4.077123    1.657382    5.660963    0.0735429694    8.143128    8.273329    3.336283    NA  -5.733124   -0.007231569
2   aF002   Female  a   PO_P    08/02/09    09/06/09    09/13/09    35  42  298.9   313.1   14.23   4.76    10.0    5.9 0.0123  0.999   0.0134  0.996   40  0.213   0.840   0.840   0.219   0.860   0.860   0.0129  0.850   0.00025 0.25196 31.8700 31.8800 32.4680 32.3020 32.1300 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5.640012    0.059996453 4.056173    1.643836    4.056173    1.690350    5.640012    0.1065103847    8.223519    8.290480    3.321928    NA  -6.276485   -0.234465254
3   aF003   Female  a   PO_P    08/03/09    09/06/09    09/13/09    34  41  237.1   270.6   33.53   14.14   9.4 5.3 0.0227  0.992   0.0248  0.994   40  0.245   1.120   1.120   0.235   1.030   1.030   0.0238  1.075   0.00037 0.36822 36.0565 41.9355 41.6260 40.0180 39.9090 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5.509734    -0.041209334    3.925894    1.542630    3.925894    1.674895    5.509734    0.0910560222    7.889352    8.080018    3.232661    NA  -5.392895   0.104336660
82  bM001   Male    b   PO_P    08/02/09    08/31/09    09/07/09    29  36  468.1   371.7   -96.38  -20.59  10.7    6.8 0.0049  0.999   0.0056  1.000   40  0.228   0.350   0.350   0.222   0.330   0.330   0.0053  0.340   0.00026 0.25735 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5.782468    0.366214334 4.198628    1.950054    4.198628    1.719513    5.640012    -0.0844204671   8.870673    8.537995    3.419539    NA  -7.559792   -1.556393349
157 cM022   Male    c   PO_P    08/03/09    10/31/09    11/07/09    89  96  451.1   402.4   -48.71  -10.80  11.3    6.9 0.0024  0.995   0.0026  0.995   10  0.091   0.110   0.028   NA  NA  NA  0.0025  0.028   0.00152 1.51515 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5.897342    0.214325251 4.313502    1.798165    4.313502    1.683895    5.897342    0.1000552907    8.817303    8.652486    3.498251    NA  -8.643856   -5.158429363
```

**Explanation of what I'm looking to accomplish:**

This experiment was attempting to determine if a particular feeding regime (Treatment) had an effect on the after-experiment mass of the subject (ln_postmass_mg).  The mass of each individual was measured twice, once at the beginning (ln_premass_mg), and once at the end of the feeding regime.  Sex, Treatment, and Measured are all categorical variables.

I have generated some R code, but the output does not match the SAS code, which it shouldn't, as I don't believe it's coded for repeated measures.  It's not clear to me if I need to transpose or otherwise manipulate my dataframe in R to perform additional analyses, or what.  I seem to be reading multiple different approaches to repeated measures problems, and am not sure which, if any, apply to my particular problem.  If anyone can put me in the right track to learn how to write the additional lines of code necessary for the R equivalent, or have suggestions, I'd much appreciate it.

**SAS Code**:

```
/* test for effect of diet regime */
/* repeated measures ANOVA for mass */
proc glm data=No_diet_lab;
class measured sex Treatment; 
model ln_premass ln_postmass=Measured Sex Treatment Measured*Sex Measured*Treatment Sex*Treatment  Measured*Sex*Treatment /nouni;
repeated time 2;
```

**R Code**:

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
model <- lm(cbind(ln_premass_mg, ln_postmass_mg) ~ Sex + Treatment + Measured + Sex:Treatment + Sex:Measured + Measured:Treatment + Sex:Treatment:Measured, data = diet_lab_data, na.action=na.omit)
```

Comment: You probably do not want `lm` for this. Maybe `aov` (the anova function in R) or a mixed effects model. Maybe start here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_repms.html

Comment: Please `dput` your data.frame into your question

Comment: Buckminster, I've added the output from dput and my main data frame as a URL in the post.

Answer (score 1):

**This should *hopefully* replicate your SAS output:**

First we'll put the data in long form:

```
df <- subset(diet_lab_data, select = c("SubjectID", "Sex", "Treatment", "Measured",
                                       "ln_premass_mg", "ln_postmass_mg"))

dfL <- reshape(df, varying = list(5:6), idvar = "SubjectID", direction = "long",
              v.names = "ln_mass_mg")
dfL$time <- factor(dfL$time, levels = 1:2, labels = c("pre", "post"))
head(dfL); tail(dfL)

        SubjectID    Sex Treatment Measured time ln_mass_mg
aF001.1     aF001 Female         a     PO_P  pre   8.143128
aF002.1     aF002 Female         a     PO_P  pre   8.223519
aF003.1     aF003 Female         a     PO_P  pre   7.889352
aF004.1     aF004 Female         a     PO_P  pre   8.521993
aF005.1     aF005 Female         a     PO_P  pre   8.335390
aF006.1     aF006 Female         a     PO_P  pre   8.259743
        SubjectID    Sex Treatment Measured time ln_mass_mg
cM033.2     cM033   Male         c  Melaniz post   8.163398
bF037.2     bF037 Female         b  Melaniz post   8.222070
cM032.2     cM032   Male         c  Melaniz post   8.422485
cF030.2     cF030 Female         c  Melaniz post   8.580447
cM039.2     cM039   Male         c  Melaniz post   8.710118
cM036.2     cM036   Male         c  Melaniz post   8.049849
```

That's better. Now we fit the model using `aov` and specifying `time` as a within subjects factor.

```
aovMod <- aov(ln_mass_mg ~ Sex * Treatment * Measured * time +
              Error(SubjectID/time), data = dfL)
```

All that being said, **I'm not sure this is the appropriate analysis**, as your design is unbalanced. Consider a mixed-effects model.

Comment: Buckminster, many thanks for the code above.  Where did you find the reshape and below functions for solving repeated measures problems?  I don't believe I'd seen them in the webpages or books I parsed through when trying to solve this on my own.

Also, to make matters worse (from the R community's perspective), I had been using Type-III SS when using SAS.  The SS in your answer are close, but obviously not within internal computation/rounding error.  Do you know of any way to get Type-III SS from your code?  I attempted to use Anova(...), but it doesn't understand "Error(SubjectID/time)".